# Putting an index on a date field in MySQL

Tags: mysql, indexing, database-indexes

Is there going to be any real benefit to me putting indexes onto date fields that are going to be mainly used in queries using stuff like.

```
dateField < 'var'
```

And

```
'var' BETWEEN dateField1 AND dateField2
```

The searches get done a lot but I am never doing a direct comparison "=" on them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes of course. Range searches will benefit from an index, just as much as equality searches.

Quoting from the [MySQL Reference Manual :: How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-indexes.html):

> **B-Tree Index Characteristics**
>
> A B-tree index can be used for column comparisons in expressions that use the =, >, >=, <, <=, or BETWEEN operators. The index also can be used for LIKE comparisons if the argument to LIKE is a constant string that does not start with a wildcard character.

In some situations, the optimiser may decide not to use the index if the range will end up to be too big, as a table scan might actually be faster. Use [`EXPLAIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/explain.html) to see which (if any) indexes will be used on your query.